# Using a list of geographic locations, and determining the X closest locations to a user-defined location

Tags: google-maps, distance, excel, cost-path

I've got a list of geographical locations in an Excel spreadsheet.  I want users to be able to search for a user-defined location, and then have the X number of closest locations from the list pulled up and displayed, sorted by nearest to farthest by travel time via car.  I know Excel alone obviously can't do this.

I have minimal/no programming knowledge.  Just an Excel tinkerer.  I figure that, at a minimum, this would require utilization of a mapping service like Google Maps or Mapquest.

Answer (score 4):

A possible solution would be to use postgresql, postgis, pgrouting and osm2pgrouting.

- Insert your fixed locations in a postgis database.
- Insert the real road network in your database for the area that you need with an import of OSM data using osm2pgrouting.
- Optional: find the closest point on your road network from the user defined location.
- Use pgrouting to calculate the distance by car from user defined location to all your predefined locations ordered on distance limited by X.

My assumptions:

- You need the real road network to be able to calculate the driving distance from a user defined location to your fixed locations.
- Distance from A to B is a good substitute for driving time. This is obviously not always the case but i do not know your specific use case.

Needed skills:

- What you mainly need with this solution is SQL knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

You say you are a "Excel tinkerer". "Mapping" in Excel is possible *to some extent*. I once saw a very involved Excel dashboard application that used a line chart to plot out boundaries of a study area and then VBA to determine what portion of the study area a given point was located within - all based on X\Y locations of both the study are line vertices and point locations. It was pretty impressive. Also, these articles might be of interest:

- [How to create a thematic map in Excel](http://www.excelcharts.com/blog/how-to-create-thematic-map-excel/)
- [Geo-scatterplot or the poor man’s GIS](http://www.excelcharts.com/blog/geo-scatterplot-or-the-poor-mans-gis/)

I don't necessarily condone or encourage these as solutions (as there are much better true GIS ones such as mrg's answer to this question), but like I said earlier, you said you were a Excel tinkerer with no-programming knowledge - which begs the question: What's your GIS knowledge level?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the Google Maps API has a service for this:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix.html

Limit of 25 destinations, though.

You might also be able to leverage the api form http://www.mapnificent.net/, though it's based on public transportation.

Answer (score 1):

I found an article called [Calculate distance in Google spreadsheet](http://winfred.vankuijk.net/2010/12/calculate-distance-in-google-spreadsheet/) that may be of use.

It would take some tweaking to do exactly what you want, I think -- and Google's daily API caps could hinder you, but it's an interesting approach.

[image]